# How do I get a value nested inside two assign functions and a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, generator

I'm writing a NodeJS module that copies a bunch of folders over from Dropbox, and creates a directory based on the folder structure. The part that is giving me a headache is that I need to get the names of all the folders in the main directory, then the names of all the files within a folder before moving on to the next function.

Here is my process right now:

1. Get the list of folders in main directory using dropboxClient.readdir()
2. Iterate through the folders and get the names sub-folders (again with dropboxClient.readdir())
3. Iterate through these sub-folders and get the names of the files.
4. If the file is a markdown file, add the name to a list
5. Return the list of all markdown files in the sub-directories

and some pseudocode:

```
function getListOfFiles() {

    var subfolders = [];
    var fileNames = [];

    dbClient.readdir('', function(error, folders) {

      folders.forEach(function(folder, index) {

        subfolders.push(folder);
        dbClient.readdir('/'+folder, function(error, subfolders) {

          subfolders.forEach(function(subfolder, index) {

            dbClient.readdir('/'+folder+'/'+subfolder, function(error, files) {

              files.forEach(function(file, index) {

                if (isMarkdownFile) {
                  fileNames.push(file)
                }

              });

            });
          });
        });
      }
    });

    return fileNames;

}
```

I've looked into a handful of packages that seem like they are supposed to solve this scenario, as well as JS Generators, but I'm not sure what the simplest solution should be. My code runs fine on Node 0.11.3, so generators are an options, but that's a new concept for me, and I can't seem to find examples that match up to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utilize the [async package](https://github.com/caolan/async). Specifically, the [`each`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries), or [`eachLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) for the loops, as well as [`waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) and [`series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) for control flow.

I'd recommend reading up on... each... of the `each` functions to figure out which is efficient and consistent/reliable for your situation.

```
function getListOfFiles(callback) {

    async.waterfall([

        // get a list of the top level folders
        function (cb) {

            dbClient.readdir('', function (error, topLevelFolders) {
                if (error) return cb(error);

                cb(null, topLevelFolders);  // pass the folders to the next function (this is the "waterfall")
            });

        },

        // get an array of all topLevel/subFolders combos
        function (topLevelFolders, cb) {

            var everySubFolder = [];

            async.each(topLevelFolders, function (folder, subFolderCallback) {

                dbClient.readdir(folder, function (error, subFolders) {
                    if (error) return subFolderCallback(error);

                    everySubFolder = everySubFolder.concat(subFolders);
                });

            }, function (error) {
                if (error) return cb(error);

                cb(null, everySubFolder); // pass all the folder/subfolder combos to the next function
            });
        },

        // get an array of all the files in each folder/subfolder
        function (everySubfolder, cb) {

            var fileNames = [];

            async.each(everySubFolder, function (folder, fileNameCallback) {

                dbClient.readdir(folder, function (error, files) {
                    if (error) return fileNameCallback(error);

                    fileNames = fileNames.concat(files);
                    fileNameCallback();
                });

            }, function (error) {
                if (error) return cb(error);

                cb(null, fileNames); // pass every file combo to the waterfall callback function
            });

        }

    ], function (error, fileNames) {
        if (error) return callback(error);

        callback(null, fileNames); // all done! Every file combo goes the function's callback!
    });
}
```

When you use it, you'll do:

```
getListOfFiles(function (err, files) {
    // Voila! here are all your files
});
```

DEFINITELY add the `.each` error handling. If it bumps into an error during the loops, it will continue looping without it. Which, # of files dependent, could be a little while.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the breakdown I was looking for.